# Align legend label to text

Tags: pgfplots, align, legend

I have this MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\definecolor{nrgray}{HTML}{F0F0F0}

\newcommand{\graphTripleData}[4]{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
        legend style={
            at={(1.5,1)}
        },
        legend entries={
            No references,Positive,Negative
        },
        clip bounding box=upper bound,
        hide axis,
        xbar, 
        reverse legend, 
        nodes near coords={\pgfmathfloatifflags{\pgfplotspointmeta}{0}{}{\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotspointmeta}#4}}]

\addplot
[fill=nrgray]
coordinates 
    {(#3,0)};

\addplot
[fill=red]
coordinates 
    {(#2,0)};

\addplot
[fill=green]
coordinates
    {(#1,0)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\graphTripleData{0}{10}{90}{\%}\\
FAEFA

\end{document}
```

Which produces this as output:

[image: MWE]

Now as far as I understand the legend by default aligns the legend labels in the middle of the name, but as it can be seen this is not happening and they are being aligned on the top instead. How can I enforce this middle alignment?

PS: I have been reading "legend style anchor", but I am not getting to do absolutely anything with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the definition for the `xbar legend` style isn't quite correct: note how the first bar in each legend entry as a length of zero. You can correct the appearance by putting the following definition in your preamble:

```
\pgfplotsset{
/pgfplots/xbar legend/.style={
/pgfplots/legend image code/.code={%
\draw[##1,/tikz/.cd, bar width=3pt,yshift=-0.1em,bar shift=0pt]
plot coordinates {(0.8em, 0cm) (0.6em, 1.7*\pgfplotbarwidth)};},
}
}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\definecolor{nrgray}{HTML}{F0F0F0}

\pgfplotsset{
/pgfplots/xbar legend/.style={
/pgfplots/legend image code/.code={%
\draw[##1,/tikz/.cd, bar width=3pt,yshift=-0.1em,bar shift=0pt]
plot coordinates {(0.8em, 0cm) (0.6em, 1.7*\pgfplotbarwidth)};},
}
}


\newcommand{\graphTripleData}[4]{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
        legend style={
            at={(1.5,1)}
        },
        legend entries={
            No references,Positive,Negative
        },
        clip bounding box=upper bound,
        hide axis,
        xbar, 
        reverse legend, 
        nodes near coords={\pgfmathfloatifflags{\pgfplotspointmeta}{0}{}{\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotspointmeta}#4}}]

\addplot
[fill=nrgray]
coordinates 
    {(#3,0)};

\addplot
[fill=red]
coordinates 
    {(#2,0)};

\addplot
[fill=green]
coordinates
    {(#1,0)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\graphTripleData{0}{10}{90}{\%}\\
FAEFA

\end{document}
```

Comment: Aargh, I just went to get some coffee to fix that. Don't you have other things to do ? :P